# Cron job not calling by automaticalic scheduler time

Tags: magento-1.8, cron

Not working cron job.
I used code from http://inchoo.net/magento/creating-cron-script-in-magento/.
But this code works when I hit my url every one minute http://127.0.0.1/magento18/cron.php that time called my custom cron job and it works perfectly and also added status success in `cron_schedule` table.But I want every one minuate call my cron job automatically.What I miss in my code ? Please suggest me.
My `config.xml` code

```
<config>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <check_data1>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>test/observer::test</model>
                </run>
            </check_data1>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
 </config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up the Magento cronjob in your crontab. If you work in a UNIX-based environment and use BASH you could do the following.

Add this line to your crontab, set the `[magento_path]` correctly:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /[magento_path]/cron.sh
```

The crontab can be edited with running `crontab -e` in your terminal.

This will ensure that the cronjobs defined in your `config.xml` will run as specified.

Comment: In addition to this I suggest adding AOE Scheduler https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler 

This provides details in the admin so you can see the cronjob is running and when each task is set to run.

Comment: Where is crontab ? Give location of crontab. I will accept your answer plz tell me where is crontab and I also installed aeo scheduler

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: The required operating system running Magento is Linux, as you can see in the official dev docs here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html Please use Docker or Vagrant on Windows to run Magento or use a Linux derivate directly